# pyplot colorbar has an unwanted extra decimal. The top value should be 1.00 but it shows up as 1.05

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I made a contour plot and my color bar has a spurious value. The data is strictly between 0 and 1. Why does this 1.05 show up? How can I make the top number be 1.00?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1,10, 100)
z = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100**2).reshape((100, 100))
plt.contourf(x, x, z, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, vmin=0., vmax=1.)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
print(cbar.get_clim()) # (0.0, 1.0)
```

[image: colorbar problem example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When plotting the contour the `contourf` function automatically chose what it believed to be the most appropriate level values to assign a colour to each data point.  This is somewhat similar to binning data in a histogram.  Each of the segments in the colorbar reflects one of these levels.

In this case it has chosen to create 7 levels, which matplotlib is struggling (for reasons I will admit I don't understand) to fit into the colorbar.

You can get around this by specifying the number of levels the `contourf` function should use and selecting a value that gives you a more acceptable colorbar (you probably don't want to go any lower than the number of levels that was automatically chosen):

```
plt.contourf(x, x, z, 10, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: Correctly spaced ticks]

Alternatively, if you really wanted to leave `contourf` to make this decision you could adjust the ticks on the colorbar:

```
plt.contourf(x, x, z, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
plt.colorbar(ticks=np.linspace(0, 1, 5))
```

[image: Colorbar with adjusted ticks]

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is surely suboptimal.

What you need in order to customize the levels of the colorbar of a contour or contourf plot is to use its `levels` argument.

E.g. to have 10 levels with 0.1 spacing between 0 and 1, you create a linspace `np.linspace(0,1,11)` and supply it to the `levels` argument. Note that the levels denote the bin *edges*, such that we take one edge more than bins.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1,10, 100)
z = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100**2).reshape((100, 100))

levels = np.linspace(0,1,11)

plt.contourf(x, x, z, levels=levels, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, vmin=0., vmax=1.)
cbar = plt.colorbar()


plt.show()
```

[image]